# Type '({ articles }: Props) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to type 'NextPage<{}, {}>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, tsx

I'm just getting into React.js and Next.js after having used Vue.js before. I'm getting a strange typescript error, but weirdly it actually compiles despite VS Code complaining at me as though it wouldn't compile.

I'm trying to pass an array of `Article` into my home component as a prop.

Here the relevant code:

```
interface Article {
  userId: number;
  id: number;
  title: string;
  body: string;
}

interface Props {
  articles: Article | Article[];
}

const Home: NextPage = ({ articles }: Props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {/* some stuff */}
    </div>
  );
};
```

`Home` is underlined in red and when I hover over gives the error:

```
const Home: NextPage<{}, {}>
Type '({ articles }: Props) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to type 'NextPage<{}, {}>'.
  Type '({ articles }: Props) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<{}> & { getInitialProps?(context: NextPageContext): {} | Promise<{}>; }'.
    Type '({ articles }: Props) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<{}>'.
      Types of parameters '__0' and 'props' are incompatible.
        Property 'articles' is missing in type '{ children?: ReactNode; }' but required in type 'Props'.
```

Any help or insights as to what could be going on here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use `NextPage<Props>` instead of annotating the function argument.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Call it this way,

```
const Home: NextPage<Props> = ({ articles }) => {//your code}
```

you're using NextPage type, I used that instead too. It's actually better to use const Home: NextPage as that will type both the component's props and return type.

Comment: I found this useful while testing with `react-testing-library` `render` method. If you need to totally mock a page while using typescript, do `const Home: NextPage = () => <div />;`.

Comment: It works but I don't understand why. How's any different stating that the Home page receives Props before the equal sign or in the function params?

Answer (score 6):

you can write like this :

```
import React , {FC} from 'react';

interface Article {
  userId: number;
  id: number;
  title: string;
  body: string;
}

interface HomeProps {
  articles: Article[];
}

const Home : FC<HomeProps> = ({articles}) => {

console.log('articles: ', articles)

  return (
    <div>
      {/* some stuff */}
    </div>
  );
};
```

and in the container :

```
const myArticles = [
 {
   userId: 1,
   id: 1,
   title: 'my title',
   body: 'my body',
 }
]
...
return (
 <Home articles={myArticles}>
)
```