# How do I redirect a user if they do not have a session using NextJs13, NextAuth, and the t3 stack?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, next-auth

I bootstrapped my project using the [t3 stack](https://create.t3.gg/) which comes with NextAuth and tRPC. When the user is not logged in, I would like to redirect them to either the home page or the sign in page. It looks like tRPC isn't made to return redirects. Given the t3 starter code, how can I add the redirects?

Here is what I have in my component

```
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react";
import { redirect } from 'next/navigation';

...
const MyPage: NextPage = () => {
const { data: session } = useSession();
...
 if(session == null){
    return redirect("/")
  } 
 return(
  <>
    <div>Test</div>
  </>
)
}
```

Running this, I get:

Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: NEXT_REDIRECT

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
router.push('/');
```

code:

```js
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react";
import { redirect } from 'next/navigation';
import { useRouter } from "next/router"; // **updated**

const MyPage: NextPage = () => {
const { data: session } = useSession();
const router = useRouter(); // updated


 if(session == null){
    // return redirect("/") // **removed**
    return router.push('/'); // **updated**
  } 
 return(
  <>
    <div>Test</div>
  </>
)
}
```

Comment: Do you have a type safe solution? I'm running into the following type error since router.push returns a promise. Type '() => Promise<boolean | JSX.Element>' is not assignable to type 'NextPage'. I also get this error when I load the page. Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: Check this page to solve this problem:  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71013565/type-articles-props-jsx-element-is-not-assignable-to-type-nextpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71013565/type-articles-props-jsx-element-is-not-assignable-to-type-nextpage)